# How read stream .pipe(myfunction())

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

How read stream **.pipe(myfunction())**?

I try  , but give errors. How read stream of **gulp.src('./userdata.json')** and **.pipe()**? I not know how is it make.

**gulpfile.js**

```
   var upmodul = require("modul-json");
      //......
        return gulp.src('./userdata.json')
            .pipe(upmodul());
      ......//
```

---

node_modules / modul-json / **index.js**

```
'use strict';
var Stream = require('stream');


var loger = function () {

    var readable = new Stream.Readable({
        read: function (n) {

            this.push("ll");
        }
    });


}

module.exports =  loger;
```

---

**Error**

```
    [00:19:39] TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
        at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer
    -WebProg\domains\progectapi2\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\
    lib\_stream_readable.js:516:7)
        at Gulp.<anonymous> (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg\domains\p
    rogectapi2\gulpfile.js:159:9)
        at module.exports (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg\domains\pro
    gectapi2\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg
    \domains\progectapi2\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg
    \domains\progectapi2\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg\do
    mains\progectapi2\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
        at C:\Users\Tiki
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:362:13)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:432:11)
```

Comment: So "modul-json" is a folder?

Comment: @cviejo -  node_modules - folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gulp documentation has some information on [building a plugin](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/writing-a-plugin) that might be useful to you. Just a sample from that page talks about transforming streams.

> All gulp plugins essentially boil down to this:
>
> ```
> var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
>
> module.exports = function() {
>   // Monkey patch Transform or create your own subclass, 
>   // implementing `_transform()` and optionally `_flush()`
>   var transformStream = new Transform({objectMode: true});
>   /**
>    * @param {Buffer|string} file
>    * @param {string=} encoding - ignored if file contains a Buffer
>    * @param {function(Error, object)} callback - Call this function (optionally with an 
>    *          error argument and data) when you are done processing the supplied chunk.
>    */
>   transformStream._transform = function(file, encoding, callback) {
>     var error = null, 
>         output = doSomethingWithTheFile(file);
>     callback(error, output);
>   });
>
>   return transformStream;
> };
> ```

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'transform'     What need do?

Comment: Is that a typescript error or node? You may be better off using `through2` as the link in the answer suggests. `through2` needs to be npm installed

Comment: I looked at the node docs (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_example_simpleprotocol_parser_v2) and it appears `Transform` is in the streams package. `var Transform = require('stream').Transform;`